# Python Code Error - Sum of Numbers

Tags: python

This is the error code that I am getting with the Python Run Command, I have tried multiple ways to work this out with no answers. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "J:\Python\SumOfNumbers.py", line 24, in <module>
main ()
File "J:\Python\SumOfNumbers.py", line 15, in main
total += float(num)
NameError: global name 'num' is not defined

def main ():
# Declare varibles
line = ''
total = 0.0
number = 0.0

#Open numbers.txt file and make sure that numbers.txt is in the same
#folder as Python.

infile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

for line in infile:
    number= float(line)
    total += float(num)

# Close file
infile.close ()

# Display the total of the numbers in the file
print ('Total: ', total)

# Call the main function.
main ()
```

Comment: Please read python documentation when and how you use def and what are the indentation rules prior to creating functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you write

```
total += float(num)
```

However, num is not the name of the variable. You should have written

```
total += float(number)
```

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions.

Comment: @AndrewL. I don't understand. This is the answer to the error message he is getting, no? If this is not the topic of the question, then, what is?

Comment: It's a *simple typographical error* that is off topic. Answering encourages such questions from being asked in the future

Comment: Thank You so much, I was reading the source material and I was unable to make the code work. Thank Sophtware

Comment: @AndrewL. If I understand you correctly, what you mean by "off topic" is that the question is one that should not be asked on this site? I see. I am new to participating in SO so I didn't know that this was a concern. I am not sure if I agree with it though. Sure, It would be nice if everyone posted more interesting questions, but there are people who are new to programming and SO could be a place they could go to for help, no? I may be wrong. Maybe SO is not a place for beginners to seek help on simpler issues. Perhaps there are other places that they could go to.

Comment: @AndrewL. I see. Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I will keep  this in mind next time.

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a forum nor a tutorial, code-writing, or homework service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) are also good topics to read on the answering side. Thank you for being willing to learn about the site!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. The variable called num wasn't initialized, in your program it was called number. Watch out you indents as python uses them to define code blocks.

```
def main():
    line = ''
    total = 0.0
    number = 0.0

    # Open numbers.txt file and make sure that numbers.txt is in the same
    # folder as Python.
    infile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

    for line in infile:
        number = float(line)
        total += float(number)

    # Close file
    infile.close()

    # Display the total of the numbers in the file
    print ('Total: ', total)

# Call the main function.
main()
```